# Problem detecting if UITableView has scrolled to the bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm using the following code to detect if I've reached the bottom of a UITableView

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ 
    if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y >= (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height)) {
        NSLog(@"bottom!");
        NSLog(@"%@", [self getLastMessageID]);
        [self getMoreStuff:[self getLastMessageID]];
    }

}
```

This works fine, but the only problem is when the user is pulling the tableview down (like pull to refresh) the code fires. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this way

```
    if(self.tableview.contentOffset.y<0){
              //it means table view is pulled down like refresh
              return;
            }
else if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y >= (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height)) {
        NSLog(@"bottom!");
        NSLog(@"%@", [self getLastMessageID]);
        [self getMoreStuff:[self getLastMessageID]];
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget the tab bar :(

Answer (score 0):

Store the last position of the scrollview in your didScroll method. If you detect a scroll down and the last position was already the bottom of the scrollview then you ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another algorithm to detect, that you reached the bottom of table view. For example, look at the cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath to the indexPath of a current cell and if the number of row in IndexPath equals to the number of rows in your data array, then you reached a bottom.