# uitableview willdisplaycell delegate is strange

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I've been working around the tableview and got stuck on the following issue.

As far as I understand, the `willDisplayCell` delegate method should allow me to access the current cell design.

**My issue is:** it does not work properly. That delegate function runs only five times when trying to display 80 cells. Regardless of anything other than this function, writing a line of code in the delegate function makes it work well.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == comment_arr.count - 1 {
        print("end")
        // (1)self.comment_height.constant =  self.comment_table.contentSize.height + 30
    }
    // (2)self.comment_height.constant =  self.comment_table.contentSize.height + 30
}
```

If the (1) line exists, it doesn't work. But if the (2) line exists, it works well.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: try an alternative method to detect reaching the tableview's end.. I don't recommend using "willDisplayCell", even if it worked with you though, for many reasons.. 

check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015228/detect-when-uitableview-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: Does `print("end")` ever print anything? If not, the logic in your if statement may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the number of rows in section. Then find the last item

```
let totalRow = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
        if(indexPath.row == totalRow - 1)
        {
           print("end")
            return
        }
```

Comment: Okay, Your answer is helpful, I solve this problem by here https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-self-sizing-table-view-2635ac3df8ab

Answer (score -1):

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

is called before willDisplayCell

the topic was covered in full and detailed way here:
[TableView methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988450/ios-uitableview-whats-the-different-between-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willd)